# mvvmcross windows phone 8 custom binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, binding, mvvmcross

I want to do a custom binding.
When a property in the the ServerViewModel changes, I want to call a function in the corresponding ServerView.
Based on N-28 I can do this for Android, but how to do it for Windows phone 8?

Core:
ServerViewModel.cs

```
private bool _textUpdate;
public bool TextUpdate
{
  get { return _textUpdate; }
  set
  {
 _  textUpdate = value;
    if (value) {
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => TextUpdate);
    }
  }
}
```

Android:
Setup.cs:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
  registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ServerView>(
      "SERVERVIEW",
      dcs => new ServerViewTargetBinding(dcs));
  base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
```

Android ServerViewTargetBinding.cs

```
public class ServerViewTargetBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
  public ServerViewTargetBinding(ServerView target)
  : base(target)
  {
    //only one way target.MyCountChanged += TargetOnMyCountChanged;
  }

  protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void SetValue(object value)
  {
    var target = Target as ServerView;

    if (target == null)
     return;

    target.ServerCallback((bool)value);
  }

  public override Type TargetType
  {
    get { return typeof(ServerView); }
  }

  public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
  {
    get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
  }
}
```

Android ServerView.cs

```
set.Bind(this).For("SERVERVIEW").To(vm => vm.TextUpdate);

public void ServerCallback(bool value)
{
  if (_isUpdating)
    return;

  _isUpdating = true;
  try{
    _text.SetText(value);
  }
  finally{
    _isUpdating = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mvvmcross bindings - including custom bindings - in windows, then you need to include the bindingex packages - see the n=35 video for an example in WindowsStore (phone is similar). After you've done that, then you can add custom bindings and use them in `Bi.nd` statements in your xaml.

Alternatively, you might be able to achieve your  required effect using Attached Properties - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can see You can do a valueconverter call, but how can You do a callback function call, from the viewModel to the view?

Comment: I can do all the call, as in android except         protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
        {


            registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ServerView>(
                            "SERVERVIEW",
                            dcs => new ServerViewTargetBinding(dcs));
            base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

        }